Why are my newly created bone collections not appearing in the 'rig layers' panel?
Running Blender 4.2
Hit a snag that I haven't found a solution for after days of trawling. I created some new bone collections to match some new bones that I added onto my metarig. It's a dragon character, so the wings and wing 'fingers' required new bones and controls. Though almost every aspect of the rig works fine, the new bone collections I created aren't showing up in the 'rig layers' panel that's used to select/deselect bone collections. This is strange since selecting/deselecting the new bone collections in edit mode works perfectly.
I have tried this suggestion here...:
How to update existing Rigify bone layers?
...but hit a roadblock when I realised that the Data panel had a different UI. I also tried reloading the python script and ensuring that auto-update of scripts was enabled in preferences, but with no luck.
I have attached 3 images that may help explain my issue better. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!




Hi Lucky, please use the 'answer' field to post your answer.

Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, rephrasing the problem to read like an actual question or expose a problem, while the solution is written as a separate answer in the proper section below? See How do I write a good answer?

Thank you for the suggestions, post has been amended.

Dug around the UI a bit, and found the 'Bone Collection UI' panel here: Data >Rigify >Bone Collection UI. Please note that the original metarig must be selected. Don't know how I missed it, in hindsight. But selecting your currently missing bone collection may show a 'UI row' of 0. Changing this value will place the bone collection in it's matching position on the 'rig layers' panel. Once it's in, you can edit the UI however you wish. Make sure you regenerate the rig for your UI changes to show up!


An error, or a warning? If you're getting errors uploading images, you can post a bug report on MSE. If your images are too large, you can find online converters to compress them.

Can't remember, but I tried it again tonight with the same image and it's working now (y)

Excellent! Consider marking your answer as accepted, it will make it more visible.
